# Using Windows Media Player SDK in a commercial software

Tags: software, licensing

Does anyone know what license does the Windows Media Player SDK use? I am implementing a video player to commercial software written in Visual Basic and I couldn't find any license information regarding the Windows Media Player SDK. In the program I am using WMPLib and Windows Media Player ActiveX component and was wondering what I need to be able to sell this software. Do I need a license for this?

Answer (score 1):

It does not offer such a license. You would need to contract Microsoft legal via their website. It is a normal closed product.